# Blogger pagger code not working

Tags: html, blogger, pager

I am using blogger custom template for my blogger but my pager code not working here. Please help to solve problem. I tried many code on internet but page number not linking to next page.

I posted code of div that not working:

```
<div class="pagenav">
<script type="text/javascript">
        var pageNaviConf = {
        perPage: 6,
            numPages: 5,
            firstText: "First",
            lastText: "Last",
            nextText: "Next",
            prevText: "Prev"
        }
        </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
        function pageNavi(o){var m=location.href,l=m.indexOf("/search/label/")!=-1,a=l?m.substr(m.indexOf("/search/label/")+14,m.length):"";a=a.indexOf("?")!=-1?a.substr(0,a.indexOf("?")):a;var g=l?"/search/label/"+a+"?updated-max=":"/search?updated-max=",k=o.feed.entry.length,e=Math.ceil(k/pageNaviConf.perPage);if(e<=1){return}var n=1,h=[""];l?h.push("/search/label/"+a+"?max-results="+pageNaviConf.perPage):h.push("/?max-results="+pageNaviConf.perPage);for(var d=2;d<=e;d++){var c=(d-1)*pageNaviConf.perPage-1,b=o.feed.entry[c].published.$t,f=b.substring(0,19)+b.substring(23,29);f=encodeURIComponent(f);if(m.indexOf(f)!=-1){n=d}h.push(g+f+"&max-results="+pageNaviConf.perPage)}pageNavi.show(h,n,e)}pageNavi.show=function(f,e,a){var d=Math.floor((pageNaviConf.numPages-1)/2),g=pageNaviConf.numPages-1-d,c=e-d;if(c<=0){c=1}endPage=e+g;if((endPage-c)<pageNaviConf.numPages){endPage=c+pageNaviConf.numPages-1}if(endPage>a){endPage=a;c=a-pageNaviConf.numPages+1}if(c<=0){c=1}var b='<span class="pages">Pages '+e+' of '+a+"</span> ";if(c>1){b+='<a href="'+f[1]+'">'+pageNaviConf.firstText+"</a>"}if(e>1){b+='<a href="'+f[e-1]+'">'+pageNaviConf.prevText+"</a>"}for(i=c;i<=endPage;++i){if(i==e){b+='<span class="current">'+i+"</span>"}else{b+='<a href="'+f[i]+'">'+i+"</a>"}}if(e<a){b+='<a href="'+f[e+1]+'">'+pageNaviConf.nextText+"</a>"}if(endPage<a){b+='<a href="'+f[a]+'">'+pageNaviConf.lastText+"</a>"}document.write(b)};(function(){var b=location.href;if(b.indexOf("?q=")!=-1||b.indexOf(".html")!=-1){return}var d=b.indexOf("/search/label/")+14;if(d!=13){var c=b.indexOf("?"),a=(c==-1)?b.substring(d):b.substring(d,c);document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="/feeds/posts/summary/-/'+a+'?alt=json-in-script&callback=pageNavi&max-results=99999"><\/script>')}else{document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="/feeds/posts/summary?alt=json-in-script&callback=pageNavi&max-results=99999"><\/script>')}})();
        //]]>
</script><script type="text/javascript" src="/feeds/posts/summary?alt=json-in-script&amp;callback=pageNavi&amp;max-results=99999"></script><span class="pages">Pages 2 of 6</span> <a href="/?max-results=6">Prev</a><a href="/?max-results=6">1</a><span class="current">2</span><a href="/search?updated-max=2016-02-11T02%3A17%3A00-08%3A00&amp;max-results=6">3</a><a href="/search?updated-max=2016-02-01T23%3A45%3A00-08%3A00&amp;max-results=6">4</a><a href="/search?updated-max=2016-01-31T21%3A48%3A00-08%3A00&amp;max-results=6">5</a><a href="/search?updated-max=2016-02-11T02%3A17%3A00-08%3A00&amp;max-results=6">Next</a><a href="/search?updated-max=2016-01-27T01%3A22%3A00-08%3A00&amp;max-results=6">Last</a>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It is customary to explain what you want the code to do, and what you are seeing instead. "Not working" describes 90% of the posts on this site and therefore not specific enough. ;-)

Comment: my blog is sikhtera.blogspot.com the page navigation is not working at bottom it is showing page number but they are disabled when i hover over page number it not showing as link..any thing else you want please tell

Answer (score 0):

use this :

```html
<div class='pagenavi'>
<script type='text/javascript'>
var pageNaviConf = {
perPage: 7,
numPages: 5,
firstText: &quot;First&quot;,
lastText: &quot;Last&quot;,
nextText: &quot;&#187;&quot;,
prevText: &quot;&#171;&quot;
}
</script>
<script type='text/javascript'>/*

 * Awesome Blogger Page Navigation by Onlinetrick *
 * Rev 248 on May 7, 2010 *
 * Source at http://code.google.com/p/rilwis/source/browse/trunk/blogger *

*/


function pageNavi(o){
 var m=location.href,
  l=m.indexOf("/search/label/")!=-1,
  a=l?m.substr(m.indexOf("/search/label/")+14,m.length):"";
  
 a=a.indexOf("?")!=-1?a.substr(0,a.indexOf("?")):a;
 
 var g=l?"/search/label/"+a+"?updated-max=":"/search?updated-max=",
  k=o.feed.entry.length,
  e=Math.ceil(k/pageNaviConf.perPage);
 
 if(e<=1){
  return
 }
 var n=1,
  h=[""];
 l?h.push("/search/label/"+a+"?max-results="+pageNaviConf.perPage):h.push("/?max-results="+pageNaviConf.perPage);
 
 for(var d=2;d<=e;d++){
  var c=(d-1)*pageNaviConf.perPage-1,
   b=o.feed.entry[c].published.$t,
   f=b.substring(0,19)+b.substring(23,29);
   
  f=encodeURIComponent(f);
  
  if(m.indexOf(f)!=-1){
   n=d
  }
  
  h.push(g+f+"&max-results="+pageNaviConf.perPage)
 }
 
 pageNavi.show(h,n,e)
}

pageNavi.show=function(f,e,a){
 var d=Math.floor((pageNaviConf.numPages-1)/2),
  g=pageNaviConf.numPages-1-d,
  c=e-d;
 if(c<=0){
  c=1
 }
 endPage=e+g;
 if((endPage-c)<pageNaviConf.numPages){
  endPage=c+pageNaviConf.numPages-1
 }
 if(endPage>a){
  endPage=a;
  c=a-pageNaviConf.numPages+1
 }
 if(c<=0){
  c=1
 }
 
 var b='<span class="pages">Page '+e+' of '+a+"</span> ";
 
 if(c>1){
  b+='<a href="'+f[1]+'">'+pageNaviConf.firstText+"</a>"
 }
 if(e>1){
  b+='<a href="'+f[e-1]+'">'+pageNaviConf.prevText+"</a>"
 }
 for(i=c;i<=endPage;++i){
  if(i==e){
   b+='<span class="current">'+i+"</span>"
   }else{
   b+='<a href="'+f[i]+'">'+i+"</a>"
  }
 }
 if(e<a){
  b+='<a href="'+f[e+1]+'">'+pageNaviConf.nextText+"</a>"
 }
 if(endPage<a){
  b+='<a href="'+f[a]+'">'+pageNaviConf.lastText+"</a>"
 }
 
 document.write(b)
};
 
(function(){var b=location.href;if(b.indexOf("?q=")!=-1||b.indexOf(".html")!=-1){return}var d=b.indexOf("/search/label/")+14;if(d!=13){var c=b.indexOf("?"),a=(c==-1)?b.substring(d):b.substring(d,c);document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="/feeds/posts/summary/-/'+a+'?alt=json-in-script&callback=pageNavi&max-results=99999"><\/script>')}else{document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="/feeds/posts/summary?alt=json-in-script&callback=pageNavi&max-results=99999"><\/script>')}})();</script>
<div class='clear'/>
</div>
```